# How to load html files from a folder and display them as a link on a local webpage

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I got a bit of help so I have some code to work with, but I can't seem to figure this out so, I'm looking for some more help. The task I'm working on is displaying html files as links on a local webpage, and updating this automatically as there will be a new folder(inserted into the same root folder) with a new file every day.

My problem is accessing the folders and selecting the html file which is always called main.html. The folders have a different name since it has a date in the name, but the html file is always called main.html. I want to update the page daily. Im using node and javascript.

I have tried to find online tutorials, but they always just read the files, and do not display files as links or update them regularly. Should I be using Express?

tutorials, tried to use writable and readable streams.

```
  var http = require("http");
  var fs = require("fs");

  var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
  var myReadStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/index.html", 
  "utf8");
  myReadStream.pipe(res);
  });

  server.listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");

  const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
  const resolve = require("path").resolve;
  const dir = _resolve(
  require("os").homedir(),
  "(Filepath for folder that gets inserted into the folder everyday)"
  );

  function getFiles(dir, ...flags) {
  const child = spawn("ls", flags);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let data = "";
    child.stdout.on("data", chunk => (data += chunk.toString()));
    child.stdout.on("err", err => reject(err.toString()));
    child.stdout.on("end", () => resolve(data));
    });
  }

  function monitorFileChanges(dir) {
   watch(dir, (event, filename) => {
    console.log(event, filename);
   });
  }
```

Im not getting any output exept the original HTML file without any more content on.

Answer (score 0):

Express Js is a web framework which has an inbuilt function to render static files. Check out this documentation [Serving static files in local](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). Please find the snippet to run an express app.

```
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express()
const port = 3000

// File path for folder that gets inserted into the folder everyday
const path = "/var/";

// To render files in configured path
app.use(express.static(path))

// Root Path
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    getFileList(path);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

//To get list of files in the folder
 function getFileList(path) {
    if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
        fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {
            //handling error
            if (err) {
                return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
            }
            homePage(files);
        });
    }
}

// Generate home page with the available list of files as hyperlink
function homePage(fileList) {
    let data = "<ol> \n";
    for (let file in fileList) {
        data += `<li> <a href="/${fileList[file]}"> ${fileList[file]} </li> \n`
    }
    data += "</ol>";
    fs.writeFile('index.html', data)
}

// Start express app and listen the configured port
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`))
```